# Why the index of first row is picked when I click any row in gridview?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, webforms

When I click EDIT in any row then why does it pick the index of first row ?

Edit button inside Gridiview:

```
<asp:ButtonField CommandName="cmdEdit" HeaderText="Edit" ImageUrl="~/assets/global/images/shopping/edit.png" ButtonType="Image" ControlStyle-Width="25px" ControlStyle-Height="20px" />
```

Code behind EDIT:

```
protected void grdviewLandInfo_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {              
         int Index = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
         Int32 LandInfoID =  Convert.ToInt32(grdviewLandInfo.DataKeys[Index].Value);
         short UserID = Convert.ToInt16(Session["UserID"]);

         short LandTypeID = Convert.ToInt16(grdviewLandInfo.Rows[Index].Cells[6].Text);
```

Comment: It is because you have not specified any `CommandArgument` attribute of `<asp:ButtonField...`

Comment: but in other pages i haven't specified any command argument and that works

Comment: and CommantArgument isn't an attribute of buttonField

Comment: That's because `CommandArgument` is not specified for button so `e.CommandArgument` is null on `RowCommand` then `Convert.ToInt32` returns 0 for null value and 0 is your first row index

Comment: Ahhh, now its interesting, `CommandArgument` *isn't an attribute of ButtonField*. Never used buttonfield, I always used LinkButton with CommandName and CommandArgument, so looking into it.

Comment: sorry ca you be more precise I am naive

Comment: Nothing, I have never used ButtonField so the conscience was that if it has CommandName then CommandArgument must be there. Have you tried to watch value of `e.CommandArgument` in *debug* mode?

Answer (score 0):

Add buttonfield in commandArgument attribute like below.

```
<asp:ButtonField CommandName="cmdEdit" HeaderText="Edit" ImageUrl="~/assets/global/images/shopping/edit.png" CommandArgument='<%# ((GridViewRow) Container).RowIndex %>' ButtonType="Image" ControlStyle-Width="25px" ControlStyle-Height="20px" />
```

Comment: but in other pages i haven't specified any command argument and that works

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
protected void grdviewLandInfo_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
  if(e.CommandName == "cmdEdit")
   {
    try
    {  
       ...
```

Comment: no, the problem is before IF statement, it doesn't pick correct INDEX

Answer (score 0):

Try this one...

```
if (e.CommandName.Equals("cmdEdit"))
{
        GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)((Control)e.CommandSource).Parent.Parent;
    Int32 LandInfoID =  Convert.ToInt32(grdviewLandInfo.DataKeys[row.RowIndex].Value);
}
```

Hope this helps...